# Perl explicitly using module UNIVERSAL causes a module to not export any symbols

Tags: perl

I have two perl modules where one is the "object base" and the other imports functions from this "object base" module. When I compile the second module (`perl -c Foo/Bar/NewObject.pm`) it compiles without any warnings.

The issue is if I include the UNIVERSAL module in compiling the second module (`perl -MUNIVERSAL -Mstrict -wc Foo/Bar/NewObject.pm`) it throws warnings like:
*"set" is not exported by the Foo::Bar::Object module*

So my question is why does including UNIVERSAL cause the Exporter function to fail exporting symbols from the 'object base' model?

An example of what the modules look like are below.

#### object base:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  

use strict;  

package Foo::Bar::Object;

use Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw( new set get update create  );

... 

1;
```

#### second module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  

use strict;  

package Foo::Bar::NewObject;

use Foo::Bar::Object qw( new set get );

... 

1;
```

Comment: The code you have here works just fine for me. The problem is very likely in code you did not show.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `UNIVERSAL`?  What are you trying to achieve? All packages already inherit from `UNIVERSAL` by default.

Comment: Tip: `perl -wc Foo/Bar/NewObject.pm` is not as good as `perl -wce'use Foo::Bar::NewObject`. Don't know if it matters here.

Comment: Do you have any circular dependencies, by any chance (A uses B and B uses A, maybe not directly)? Check out [http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by follow what @ikegami linked in the comments. I had to wrap the @EXPORT in a BEGIN {} block and that seemed to work.

There must have been a module trying to use the methods before they were exported.